# quick download files using python

Tags: python, web, urllib

I am currently trying to download files from more than 800,000 urls. Each url represent on .txt file.

I am using dataframe to store all the

**url information:**

```
index       Filename                                         
4           .../data/1000015/0001104659-05-006777.txt
5           .../data/1000015/0000950123-05-003812.txt
......
```

**Code:**

```
  for i in m.index:
     download = 'ftp:/.../' + m['Filename'][i]
     print download
     urllib.urlretrieve(download, '%s''%s.txt' % (m['Co_name'][i], m['Date'][i]))
```

This method works, however, the speed is quite low, it downloads 15 files in 7 minutes. Considering I have more than 800,000 files. It is more than 9 month...So I was wondering could anyone help me improve this? Thank you so much.

---

After Some really helpful comments, I made some changes, Is the following a good way to do multiprocessing?

**Code:**

```
def download(file):
  import ftplib
  ftp = ftplib.FTP('XXXX')
  ftp.login()
  for i in m.index:
  a = m['Filename'][i]
  local_file = os.path.join("local_folder", '%s %s.txt' % (m['Co_name'][i], m['Data'][i]))
  fhandle = open(local_file,'wb')
  print fhandle
  ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+a, fhandle.write)
  fhandle.close()

m=pd.read_csv('XXXX.csv', delimiter=',', index_col='index')

pool = Pool(10)
pool.map(download, m)
```

Comment: use multiple threads

Comment: what is the average size of the files?

Comment: @kums, on averge is 100kb

Comment: @laike9m, Thanks I will try. Is it possible that read data from dataframe is a bit slow?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: @laike9m, OK, thanks. So the only solution is use multiple threads?

Comment: The only decent solution is to use threads. You could use multiprocessing of course, but for IO bound work like this multiprocessing is a waste.

Comment: @laike9m, I have updated a bit. Could you please help me to make it faster? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way, you establish a new connection for every file. This means you lose a few seconds for every file where nothing is downloaded.

You can reduce this by using ftplib (https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html), which allows to establish a single connection and retrieve one file by one over this connection.

Still, there is time where no data is transferred. To use the maximum bandwith, use threads, to downloads several files in parallel. But note that some servers limit the numbers of parallel connections.

However, the time overhead should not exceed a few seconds, lets say 5 in worst case. Then, about 25s for a 100kB file is very very slow.
I guess your connection is very slow, or the server is. If FTP is not the standard way, may be the FTP server of your main frame is shut down when a connection is terminated and started when a connection is established? Then, FTPlib should help. 
Still, an overhead of half a second means 400.000 seconds of waiting. So, downloading in parallel makes sense.

May be, you first try a FTP client like filezilla and check what bandwith is possible with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is faster. As you mentioned, I really should use multiple threads.

Comment: Hi, @sweber. I have updated my code. Do you think it is a valid way to reduce time?

Comment: Hi! It should work. Why don't you just test it? As said, check if the server allows to download 10 files in parallel. And it may be even better to open 10 connections once and download all files via those. It's more code and you have to check if its worth it.